# How to get length of current group in data.table grouping?

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I know this can be achieved with other packages, but I'm trying to do it in `data.table` (as it seems to be the fastest for grouping).

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a=c(1,2,2,3))
dt[,length(a),by=a]
```

results in

```
   a V1
1: 1  1
2: 2  1
3: 3  1
```

whereas

```
df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,2,3))
ddply(df,.(a),summarise,V1=length(a))
```

produces

```
  a V1
1 1  1
2 2  2
3 3  1
```

which is a more sensible results. Just wondering why `data.table` is not giving the same results, and how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The data.table way to do this is to use special variable, `.N`, which keeps track of the number of rows in the current group. (Other special variables include `.SD`, `.BY` (in version 1.8.2) and `.I` and `.GRP` (available from version 1.8.3). All are documented in `?data.table`):

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a=c(1,2,2,3))

dt[, .N, by = a]
#    a N
# 1: 1 1
# 2: 2 2
# 3: 3 1
```

To see why what you tried didn't work, run the following, checking the value of `a` and `length(a)` at each browser prompt:

```
dt[, browser(), by = a]
```

Comment: +1 @jamborta Also see [FAQ 2.10](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) for some background. The reason for it is efficiency to avoid repeating the same group value through a potentially long vector (time and space). In ops with longer vectors, R will recycle length 1 vectors anyway, if and when needed.   So `.N` is the way to go here.